# Subtract current price from previous price in same table with different date with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to subtract `Maxprice` of `8/10/2018` from `Maxprice` of `5/10/2018` and  `Maxprice` of `5/10/2018` from `Maxprice` of `4/10/2018` and so on for that `configurationID`.

After getting that I want to update that change value to the another table. I need an optimized query for that.

I have 500 configurations in my table and each configuration has 1000 rows of data.

Comment: Please include your data directly in the question, and also show what the expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQL Lag() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx) to read a previous column value in an order set of data

Please try following SQL Select statement

```
select
*, lag(MaxPrice,1) over (partition by ConfigurationId order by CreatedOn) previousPrice
from PriceHistory
```